# How can I set the output filename in Flash Builder 4?

Tags: flash, flash-builder, flashbuilder4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Output filename in Flash Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457143/output-filename-in-flash-builder)

Is there a way to set the filename for the exported swf file in Flash Builder 4 other than renaming the main mxml file?

Compiler parameter -output is not accepted as I use Flash Builder to compile...